# SQL join on dates returing multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to join 2 tables. One has measurement data for parameters from manufacturing batches, the other limits for the tested parameters and dates that the limits were changed. The limits table can have blank limits or '0' limits which should be ignored.
I want to join the tables so that the limit that should be applied to that measurement is shown, i.e the maximum parameterlimitdate before or equal to the measurement date.
The code I have is removing limits from dates greater than the measurement date, but including older limits. 
Appreciate any help to review my code and suggest corrections.

```
SELECT data.batch,
       limits.parameter,
       data.measurementdate,
       data.value,
       max(limits.parameterlimitdate) AS limitdate,
       limits.lowerlimit,
       limits.upperlimit,
       CASE
           WHEN (batch.value<limits.lowerlimit
                 OR batch.value>limits.upperlimit) THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS valueoutsidelimits
FROM dbo.limits
LEFT JOIN dbo.data DATA ON limits.parameter = data.parameter
WHERE limits.parameterlimitdate<=batch.measurementdate
  AND NOT (limits.lowerlimit=0
           AND limits.upperlimit=0)
GROUP BY data.batch,
         limits.parameter,
         limits.lowerlimit,
         limits.upperlimit,
         data.value,
         data.measurementdate
```

Date table:

```
Batch   Parameter   MeasurementDate Value
A       X           20/02/2018  10.02
A       X           21/02/2018  10.01
B       X           22/02/2018  10.02
C       X           23/02/2018  10.00
D       X           20/02/2018  9.98
E       X           22/02/2018  10.01
A       Y           23/02/2018  6.25
B       Y           22/02/2018  6.31
C       Y           20/02/2018  6.35
A       Z           21/02/2018  220.3
```

Limits table:

```
    Parameter   ParameterLimitDate  LowerLimit  UpperLimit
    X           18/05/2009          9.98        10.03
    X           01/01/2010          9.98        10.02
    X           02/06/2012      
    X           01/10/2014          0           0
    X           21/02/2018          9.99        10.01
    Y           01/01/2010          6.2         6.3
    Y           05/03/2013          6.3         6.4
```

Required output:

```
Batch Parameter MeasurementDate Value   LimitDate  LowerLimit UpperLimit ValueOutsideLimits
A     X         20/02/2018      10.02   01/01/2010  9.98      10.02      0
A     X         21/02/2018      10.01   01/01/2010  9.98      10.02      0
B     X         22/02/2018      10.02   21/02/2018  9.99      10.01      1
C     X         23/02/2018      10.00   21/02/2018  9.99      10.01      0
D     X         20/02/2018      9.98    01/01/2010  9.98      10.02      0
E     X         22/02/2018      10.01   21/02/2018  9.99      10.01      0
A     Y         23/02/2018      6.25    05/03/2013  6.3       6.4        1
B     Y         22/02/2018      6.31    05/03/2013  6.3       6.4        0
A     Z         21/02/2018      220.3   



Actual output with duplicate batch parameter measurements:                          
    Batch   Parameter   MeasurementDate Value   LimitDate   LowerLimit  UpperLimit  ValueOutsideLimits
    A   X   20/02/2018  10.02   18/05/2009  9.98    10.03   0
    A   X   20/02/2018  10.02   01/01/2010  9.98    10.02   0
    A   X   21/02/2018  10.01   18/05/2009  9.98    10.03   0
    A   X   21/02/2018  10.01   01/01/2010  9.98    10.02   0
    B   X   22/02/2018  10.02   18/05/2009  9.98    10.03   0
    B   X   22/02/2018  10.02   01/01/2010  9.98    10.02   0
    B   X   22/02/2018  10.02   21/02/2018  9.99    10.01   1
    C   X   23/02/2018  10.00   18/05/2009  9.98    10.03   0
    C   X   23/02/2018  10.00   01/01/2010  9.98    10.02   0
    C   X   23/02/2018  10.00   21/02/2018  9.99    10.01   0
    D   X   20/02/2018  9.98    18/05/2009  9.98    10.03   0
    D   X   20/02/2018  9.98    01/01/2010  9.98    10.02   0
    E   X   22/02/2018  10.01   18/05/2009  9.98    10.03   0
    E   X   22/02/2018  10.01   01/01/2010  9.98    10.02   0
    E   X   22/02/2018  10.01   21/02/2018  9.99    10.01   0
    A   Y   23/02/2018  6.25    01/01/2010  6.2 6.3 0
    A   Y   23/02/2018  6.25    05/03/2013  6.3 6.4 1
    B   Y   22/02/2018  6.31    01/01/2010  6.2 6.3 1
    B   Y   22/02/2018  6.31    05/03/2013  6.3 6.4 0
    A   Z   21/02/2018  220.3
```

Comment: "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  What is your database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm using SQL server

Comment: use distinct keyword

Comment: Why isn't `data` record `C Y 20/02/2018 6.35` included in the desired result set?

Comment: Hi Giorgos, sorry for any confusion - think I must have copied some of it from a slightly different dataset I was working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want all records of table `data` returned, matched by the most recent limit valid before the data `measurementdate`. In this case you have to select from `data` *first* and *then* join with `limits`.

Having said that, one way to solve this is using `OUTER APPLY`

```
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 Parameter, ParameterLimitDate, LowerLimit, UpperLimit
   FROM limits
   WHERE limits.parameter = data.parameter AND 
      limits.parameterlimitdate <= data.measurementdate AND
      (COALESCE(limits.lowerlimit, 0) <> 0 AND COALESCE(limits.upperlimit, 0) <> 0)
   ORDER BY limits.parameterlimitdate DESC
) AS limits
```

instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

So, the actual query becomes:

```
SELECT data.batch,
       data.parameter,
       data.measurementdate,
       data.value,
       limits.parameterlimitdate AS limitdate,
       limits.lowerlimit,
       limits.upperlimit,
       CASE
           WHEN (data.value<limits.lowerlimit
                 OR data.value>limits.upperlimit) THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS valueoutsidelimits
FROM dbo.data
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 Parameter, ParameterLimitDate, LowerLimit, UpperLimit
   FROM limits
   WHERE limits.parameter = data.parameter AND 
      limits.parameterlimitdate <= data.measurementdate AND
      (COALESCE(limits.lowerlimit, 0) <> 0 AND COALESCE(limits.upperlimit, 0) <> 0)
   ORDER BY limits.parameterlimitdate DESC
) AS limits
```

Comment: HI Giorgos, Thank you for taking the time to respond to this post. This worked great with a modification to the WHERE clause to not include records where both limits are equal to 0 (I realise I didn't explain this properly in my original post!) : 'WHERE limits.parameter = data.parameter AND 
      limits.parameterlimitdate <= data.measurementdate AND
      NOT(limits.lowerlimit =  0 AND limits.upperlimit= 0)'

Comment: @AnnaLouise I'm happy I was able to help you.

Comment: The aggregation doesn't make sense to me. With `TOP 1` in `OUTER APPLY` you already get the current limit for a measurement date, so why `GROUP BY`and `max(limits.parameterlimitdate)`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, you are right. I just wrote the `OUTER APPLY` so that it yields the required record. I then copy / paste the rest of the query as the OP originally wrote it. I've fixed the query. Is it ok now?

Comment: Looks fine to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

With your LEFT JOIN you get ALL records from limits, that are not excluded by the WHERE clause. The date is also not included in your GroupBy, so you get the maximum date for each unique constellation of limits.parameter, limits.lowerlimit and limits.upperlimit.

So for example batch 'A' you get returned 01/01/2010 and 18/05/2009, because the upper limit was changed in that timeframe.

To fix it, i would suggest selecting from the batch data and connecting the limits table via INNER JOIN if there is no possibility, that no limit was available at the time of the measurement.

Comment: Thanks goetterkomplex. Unfortunately there may be parameters in the data table that will not have any limits.

Comment: You are welcome. Then you need a RIGHT JOIN in this case, as you want to know all the batches, if there is a parameter or not. Also: Is there a reason for the GROUP BY? In you example data there would'nt.